# How to interpret a string for php code?

Tags: php

I have this:

```
this string might contain `<?php echo $var; ?>` php code
```

if it was in a file, it would be just an `include` / `require` command. But this time `eval` wont work. What to do?

Comment: eval is evil.... be afraid of the devil

Comment: Better to use a placeholder and then parse it, something like `{var}`, etc.

Comment: why eval won't work? What did you try, did you extract the code using a regex for example?

Comment: @Astoria (hysteria) sorry but I already figured out myself. Wont work

Comment: @fjellfly: var_dump (eval('this string might contain <?php echo $var; ?> php code')); it gives "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING) in"

Comment: @JohnSmith What's that "(hysteria)" supposed to mean?

Comment: @MichaelJaros malapropism. Astoria-hysteria

Comment: @JohnSmith I understand, but I don't understand why you would add such a negatively connotated malapropism next to a person's name in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) says:

> eval — Evaluate a string as PHP code

It also says below:

> The code must not be wrapped in opening and closing PHP tags, ... It is still possible to leave and re-enter PHP mode though using the appropriate PHP tags.

Put `?>` in front of your string and it will become valid PHP code (empty code) followed by some text to be sent directly to the output and more fragments of PHP code properly enclosed in the PHP tags.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want to be done:

```
$var = "Hello World!";
$string = 'this string might contain `<?php echo $var; ?>` php code';
//extract command
preg_match('/<\?php(.{1,}?)\?>/',$string,$match);
//print_r($match);
//execute command
eval($match[1]);
```